# Find duplicate and copy adjacent cell into

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help getting some direction on this task.

I have two spreadsheets dumps with large quantities of information. I need to combine them into one organized sheet.

Spreadsheet A has path to the file (via hard drive), with loads of additional info needed to be retained.
Spreadsheet B had path to the file (via hard drive), and for those in the content management system, the path in the CMS.

I would like to copy spreadsheet B into worksheet 2 in spreadsheet A, then run a macro that will search for matching values (path to file via hard drive), and where the same, copy the adjacent value of worksheet B (path in CMS) and copy that in the appropriate cell in spreadsheet A.

I have a vlookup function that does exactly what I need it to do, but how do I go about and put it in a macro to run?

```
=VLOOKUP(H1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

How would I put this into a macro that returns the value, not just puts the formula in the cell?

```
Sub PCMSLookup()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("J15:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B15,'PCMS-dump'!A:B,2,FALSE)" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by recording your actions (*hint* - use relative references). When you are done, tap Alt+F11 to enter the VBE and see what you've done and where it can be improved. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Now that, I was not aware of!

Comment: If you run into trouble drop back and edit your question to include enough code that we can reproduce the difficulty and focused help should be forthcoming.

Comment: How would I put this into a macro that returns the value, not just puts the formula in the cell?

Sub PCMSLookup()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("J15:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B15,'PCMS-dump'!A:B,2,FALSE)"
End Sub

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to put the value into the cells is to block in the formula then revert the formula to the returned value.

```
Sub PCMSLookup()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    with sheets("Sheet1")   '<-set this worksheet reference properly
        LastRow = .Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        with .Range("J15:J" & LastRow)
          .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B15, 'PCMS-dump'!A:B, 2, FALSE)" 
          .cells = .value2
        end with
    end with
End Sub
```

Note that when you are within a With/End With grouping, all of the range and cell references are prefixed with a period (e.g. `.` or *full stop*). This shows that they are children of closest With/End With.